# How can I convert from a date to unix in Safari? My current solution only works in chrome

Tags: javascript, unix, safari, unix-timestamp

The `dateToUnix()` function below is meant to return a unix timestamp given a date as the parameter (in the form of "YYYY.MM.DD").

```
function dateToUnix(date) {
    return Math.floor(new Date(date).getTime() / 1000);
}

console.log(dateToUnix("2022.03.25")); // logs 1648180800 in Chrome
```

In Safari, the function returns `NaN`. How can I refactor my function so that it works in both browsers?

Comment: `"2022.03.25"` isn't supported by the specification. Some browsers can support it and other browsers return `NaN`.

Comment: Right, but how could I refactor that to make it be supported in Safari? @jabaa

Comment: Use ISO 8601 date format `"2022-03-25"` or pass separate numeric values to the `Date` constructor `new Date(2022,2,25)`. There are multiple solutions in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Your first suggestion works, thank you! @jabaa